# Add Class not working even in document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

the add class is not working even if it is in document ready. I tried both with document ready and without it. it is not working but alert is working.

```
   var $jbanner = jQuery.noConflict(true);


    if ($jbanner(window).width() < 1200) {
        alert("Less than 1200");

        $jbanner("#wad").addClass("hide");
    }
```

other code

```
 var $jbanner = jQuery.noConflict(true);
 $jbanner(document).ready(function () {

  if ($jbanner(window).width() < 1200) {
         alert("Less than 1200");

         $jbanner("#wad").addClass("hide");
    }
 })
```

With document ready function even the alert box is not working. is it conflicting with other jquerys in the page.

`#wad` is an image

```
 <img id="wad" src="images/banner.jpg"/>
```

thanks

ok this should be pretty easy, but not working for me. I just pasted what i am trying to do in a separate html file. but still not working, any help is appreciated.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
     <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var $jbanner = jQuery.noConflict(true);

    if ($jbanner(window).width() < 1200) {

        alert("Less than 1200");          
        $jbanner("#wad").addClass("hide");

    }

    else {

        alert("greater than 1200");
        $jbanner("#wad").addClass("show");

    }

   </script>
   <style type="text/css">
     .hide{display:none;}
     .show{display:block;}
   </style>
   </head>

   <body><div>
        <div id="wallpaperad">
            <a href="http://www.yaho.com" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">
                <img src="http://www.placehold.it/160x160" alt="banners" id="wad" />           </a>
        </div>
    </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

I am just trying to create a floating banner ad. that hides for smaller screen sizes.

Comment: There's no `addClass` anywhere in the code you've posted. What is your question?

Comment: If the alert is not working, then you should check your `if` condition...

Comment: @Beterraba He says the alert **is** working.

Comment: @meagar `even the alert box is not working`

Comment: @Beterraba `"it is not working but alert is working."`

Comment: Sorry, first i posted with style properties, (even it is not working)

Comment: @meagar Ok, I'll rephrase: If the alert is not working **with the document ready**, then you should check your if condition...

Comment: Works fine here (width scaled up to 12000 to force the action): http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/rGsia

Comment: Without document ready, alert box is working. But add class is not working.  With Document ready, alert box and add class is not working. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are any errors being logged to the JS console, particularly in the "document ready" case?

Comment: Please show the not working code, including the document ready function/wrapper.

Comment: You're missing the last ; after document.ready.

Comment: Yes it is working there, http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/rGsia can't understand why it is not working my page. May be conflicting with other jqueries. any suggestions

Comment: @Doodlebunch I used document ready as it was not working without document ready. if it is working in the codepen.io it should work in my page as well, as that was my original approach. Can't paste all the page code it has navbar jquery, nivo slider etc.

Comment: @Doodlebunch the semicolon is optional

Comment: @carrieathomer First suggestion is my earlier question - what is the JavaScript console telling you?

Comment: @PaulRoub Thanks rob, i don't know how to use javascript console

Comment: From Webmasters StackExchange: [How to open the JavaScript console in different browsers?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)

Comment: @PaulRoub just the plain html what i posted again above, does not show any console error.

Comment: That version shouldn't work, though, since `#wad` doesn't yet exist at the time it's called. Either using a `document..ready` function, or moving the script block to the end of the `body` tag, would be required.

Comment: @PaulRoub Thanks, for the simpler version adding document ready function worked. However in my main website, i finally found out that it is conflicting with orbit slider which i am using, eventhough i am using noconflict. disabling the orbit slider it works. unfortunately, i don't know what to do more other than including noconflict. Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

Try to without jbanner.

```
$("#wad").addClass("hide");
```

Comment: Since `jQuery` is being loaded in "no conflict" mode, there will be no predefined `$` variable (or if there is, it's being used for something else).